# Is there anyway to see the (custom) events that I logged from my Firebase app in Google Analytics?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

When browsing the events in Google Analytics for my firebase project, I cannot seem to view the (custom) parameters I am logging with each event for a longer period of time.

The only way I can see the parameters is for events logged in the last 30 minutes. In this image (https://gyazo.com/4bcb58411800e2a3de4f513d53187474) you can see in the top right corner that there is a possibility to select the parameter name and see all different values. However I want to do this for periods other than the last 30 minutes. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You need to register your custom parameters in Firebase UI under Custom Definitions section. And to be able to do that you need at least Editor role. A custom dimension has either an event scope or user scope. You can create up to:

- 50 custom dimensions and 50 custom metrics per property
- 25 uniquely named user-scoped custom dimensions

Click **Custom Definitions** under **Configure** (in the left navigation), then click **Create** custom dimensions:

- Enter Dimension name.
- Select a Scope from the drop-down menu (Event or User).
- Enter a Description for your custom dimension.
- Select an Event parameter (event scope) or User property (user scope) from the list or enter the name of a parameter/property you'll collect in the future.
- Click Save.

PS: You will see a value of "not set" for a custom dimension during the first 48 hours.